# LWC -Get PicklistOptions based on the RecordTypes

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Let's Consider I have One Picklist Field, based on the RecordType the picklist options are there.

I am using `lightning/uiObjectInfoApi` to get `ObjectInfo` in that I will get a list of `RecordTypeInfos` -> since it have the list of recordTypes Properties.  In some use case I need to form a **Map with RecordTypeId => Picklist Options.**  by using list of `RecordTypeIds`

AS below code only meant for one record type to get the Picklist value

```
 @wire(getPicklistValues, {
      recordTypeId: "$recordTypeId",
      fieldApiName: Picklist_Field_ApiName
    }) //callback function
    getPickValues({
      data,
      error}) {
      if (data) {}
```

I need to process a list to get it as a map. What is the best approach to handle this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest calling an Apex controller method for this feature.
I believe there is no builtin LWC functionality to fulfil your request.
Pseudo code could be:

**Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Map<Id, List<String>> getPicklistValuesForRecordTypes(List<Id> recordTypeIdList){
    //...build the map by using Schema
}
```

**LWC**

```
//Note: You could also call getPicklistValuesForRecordTypes imperatively
@wire(getPicklistValuesForRecordTypes, {recordTypeIdList: '$selectedRecortdTypeIds'})
wiredRecordTypePicklistMap;
```